# Reading Several URIs in ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I need to read the contents of web page for several times and extract some information out of it for which I use regular expressions. I am using `open-uri` to read contents of the page and the sample code I written is as follows:

```
require 'open-uri'

def getResults(words)
    results = []
    words.each do |word|
        results.push getAResult(word)
    end
    results
end

def getAResult(word)
    file = open("http://www.somapage.com?option=#{word}")
    contents = file.read
    file.close
    contents.match /some-regex-here/
    $1.empty? ? -1 : $1.to_f
end
```

The problem is unless I comment out `file.close` line `getAResult` returns always `-1`. When I try this code on console, `getAResult` immediately returns `-1`, but ruby process runs for another two to three seconds or so.

If I remove `file.close` line `getAResult` returns the correct result, but now `getResults` is a bunch of `-1`s except for the first one. I tried to use `curb` gem for reading the page, but similar problem appears.

This seems like an issue related with threading. However, I couldn't come up with something reasonable to search and find a corresponding solution. What do you think problem would be?

NOTE: This web page I try to read does not return results so fast. It takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

try [hpricot](https://github.com/ecarnevale/hpricot) or [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri)

it can search documents via XPath in your html file

Answer (score 0):

You should grab the match result, like the following:

```
1.9.3-327 (main):0 > contents.match /div/
=> #<MatchData "div">
1.9.3-327 (main):0 > $1
=> nil




1.9.3-327 (main):0 > contents.match /(div)/
=> #<MatchData "div" 1:"div">
1.9.3-327 (main):0 > $1
=> "div"
```

Comment: Please read the question again. This isn't about matching or regular expressions. It is about the timing that I got the contents of webpage ready and function returning the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about thread safety, then you shouldn't use the $n regexp variables. Capture your results directly, like this:

```
value = contents[/regexp/]
```

Specifically, here's a more ruby-like formatting of that method:

```
def getAResult(word)
  contents = open("http://www.somapage.com?option=#{word}"){|f| f.read }
  value = contents[/some-regex-here/]
  value.empty? ? -1 : value.to_f
end
```

The block form of #open (as above) automatically closes the file when you are done with it.